# Angular js web server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I'm new to node.js and I'm learning angular js / sails js now. For angular js, I'm using yeoman, grunt, bower as the generator and test environment, etc. But it seems the sample files start from index.html then inside it includes other js files.

I was doing some test inside the controller to do http get to another port but same domain. But I think it still consider cross site request so it's blocked and not work.

I'd another project running with sails and inside the directory there isn't like an index.html and when I run the project through sails lift then it's like somewhere calling those js file internally. As I've no cross site request issue if I use sails.

I think the issue for my case in angular js is that it start off from index.html then it loads the js from there so I will have cross site issue. But if there's a way to load my angular js project like sails lift did without loading the index.html then it should work.

Is there some type of web server for angular js while it won't load the index.html then load other controller?

Maybe I shouldn't mentioned about this CORS thing. I want to know how to load angular js without loading index.html first then loading the js. I'm wondering if there's anything like the sails lift because it just act like a zend framework where it execute the controller code like from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Index.html is a file that is typically served up by Apache (or any other) web server and is simple an HTML file for the browser to interpret.  Within there you include Javascript files and/or other HTML dependencies that will be loaded after the browser parses the index.html and sees the references to those files.

The CORS issue comes up like you said if the domain or the port is different for some served files.  In order to alleviate this problem you need to look into setting up the appropriate headers for the web server you're using or just configure it to serve both the index.html and all the rest of your files from a single port.

For a thorough explanation of how CORS works see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS also lots of other info if you just google for CORS or CORS Angular or CORS node.js (fill with whatever server you actually are using or want to use).

Comment: That doesn't help. I have to do http get to another domain. Maybe I shouldn't mentioned about this CORS thing. I want to know how to load angular js without loading index.html first then loading the js. I'm wondering if there's anything like the sails lift because it just act like a zend framework where it execute the controller code like from the backend.

Comment: AngularJS is a Javascript framework it doesn't have a server side component.

Comment: But seems sails js have this sails lift which kind of hiding the js code from the browser then when loading controller code? So for angular js then everyone can see your controller js code by view source? That's not good.

Comment: Sparkmix don't put anything that is of importance in the client side code, you can use uglification and obfuscation to make your code harder to read but can't completely obscure the details that will be executed by the client... this is true of any client software not just client software that is run in a browser, if you have a piece of software you can run it in an environment that allows you to inspect the memory the process is accessing and disassemble it.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand some fundamental things about how the web works.  All communication is done on top of the HTTP protocol, web browsers have two major components an HTML parsing/rendering engine and a JS parsing/interpreting engine.  A browser starts by making a request to a domain, if it doesn't include a specific file name after a domain the server decides what file to send in response.  The browser gets the HTML file and starts interpreting it. This is always the flow regardless of what other tech is in place.